# The IntrinsicSize is not updated in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am trying to create a layout in Compose that's consisting of a `LazyColumn`. Each item in this list is consisting of a row with two columns. Both columns are clickable and should be the height of the higher column, so that the touch target spans the whole row height. When using `IntrinsicSize.Min` on my `Row` as indicated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements)
it seems to work initially, but when scrolling up and down the heights are wrong and cut off the text or are far too large.

I also tried it with `Column` instead of `LazyColumn` and there it works.

The code I used:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Companion.Gray
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

// Renders incorrectly after scrolling down and back up
@Preview
@Composable
private fun MyLazyList() {
    LazyColumn {
        items(count = 100) {
            MyItem(it * 4)
        }
    }
}

// Renders correctly, but not lazy
@Preview
@Composable
private fun MyList() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        repeat(100) {
            MyItem(it * 4)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyItem(id: Int) {
    val title = getTitle(id)
    Row(
        Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .border(1.dp, Gray)
    ) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .weight(1.0f)
                .clickable { }) {
            Text(title)
        }
        Column(
            Modifier
                .width(48.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .clickable { },
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = id.toString())
        }
    }

}

// length of title increasing with id for demo purposes
fun getTitle(id: Int): String = (0..id).toList().joinToString { it.toString() }
```

Here is how it should look like:
[image: Correctly rendered MyList]

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Incorrectly rendered MyLazyList]

Comment: I think you accidently uploaded the same image twice, or could you point out the difference between those two?

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the images. The difference is, that the heights are far too big, probably some cached size from scrolling down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the `androidx.compose.material3:material3` version (where the Text widget comes from) to the current alpha release (`1.2.0-alpha07`) and now it works without any problems. So this was apparently a bug from that library and not from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your list item code as follows and see if the issue persists:

```
@Composable
private fun MyItem(id: Int) {
    var title by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf( getTitle(id) ) }
    // ...
}
```

Also make sure that you have the [latest version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui) of the following dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.1'
```

If that does not resolve the issue, I'd recommend to open a new Issue in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). There was a [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229673431) reported some months ago, maybe this issue is related to the fact that LazyColumn reuses / recycles a certain number of list items, and the `IntrinsicHeight` not being recalculated properly according to the current data in every list item.

Comment: I tried that, but sadly it does not make any difference.
I already used the 1.5.1 version for compose and 1.1.1 version of material3.